# Получить доступ к EditText из RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

В `RecyclerView` есть `EditText`. Как из `MainActivity` получить доступ к нему и прочитать введенные в `EditText` данные?

Comment: Тяжело ответить на подобный вопрос! Как именно вы хотите получать эти данные? Из самого айтема в ресайклере или вы будете по id запрашивать вне ресайклера или может другие варианты. Уточните вопрос, хорошо бы еще добавить код из активити в котором вы хотите получить эти данные.

Comment: Уже решила. В Адаптере в коллекцию добавляю вводимые в EditText данные, а в активити читаю их.